# 11th Doctor Who episode with Rory and Amy getting split up

Tags: doctor-who, episode-identification

I am trying to remember an episode of the 11th *Doctor Who* when Rory and Amy were his companions. I've tried looking through episode summaries in the TARDIS Data Core wiki but can't seem to find it.

In the episode, Amy and Rory are split up - they are either on the Tardis or on another ship, I think. Amy comes upon Rory, who has aged and looks very disheveled - dirty, ragged clothes, long unkempt hair and beard. He is crazy and thinks Amy is a hallucination or something. When he realizes she is real, he freaks out about how long he waited for her and tries to choke her but Amy is able to get away. Anyone know what episode this was?

Comment: lol "Rory and Amy get split up for ages" is practically a running gag. From the title alone, I think that could cover at least ... 5? different episodes/events that come to mind in <20 seconds :D
(Obviously here you've given more detail in the body, to identify the particular episode)

Comment: @Brondahl The original title was just "11th Dr. Who episode with Rory and Amy", I added the split up part to give it slightly more context.

Comment: And of course, there's an episode in which they split up, period.

Comment: Next you're going to ask about an episode where the Doctor loses access to the Tardis.

Answer (score 38):

The episode you're thinking of is called ["The Doctor's Wife"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1721226/).

In this episode the TARDIS' energy is placed into a body of a female named Idris by a sentient planetoid (named House) that wants to leave the pocket universe it lives in. In the past it has lured other Timelords to itself and consumed them. Using a Timelord distress signal it lures our Doctor to itself. When the Doctor shows up "House" takes over the TARDIS and attempts to leave its pocket universe.  While doing so it amuses itself by torturing Amy and Rory. Making them see things by manipulating time and space around them (the parts to which your question was referring).  It is to the best of my knowledge the first time the Doctor has been able to directly interact with the TARDIS and literally has a heart wrenching ending.  This episode is one of my favorites.

Comment: Writing by Neil Gaiman.  Acting by Suranne Jones.  It really doesn't get any better than that. :)

Comment: OK thanks - I missed this when doing my search - this ep also notable for being written by Neil Gaiman.

Comment: Technically House ate Tardises not Timelords.

Comment: Great answer, got the plot the asker is asking about right. Didn't get the entire plot right, though, there are some minor errors in this answer. Eg. House doesn't want to leave (I don't remember anything about a pocket universe, just a planet) until the Doctor arrives and House finds out there are no more Timelords coming

Answer (score 24):

Sounds like [The Doctor's Wife](https://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Doctor's_Wife). From the TARDIS wiki link:

> Elsewhere, as they run through the TARDIS corridors, Amy and Rory must contend with House's mind games; first, he separates them, then seemingly places Rory in a faster time stream than Amy whereby he ages and dies in a matter of minutes, devastating her. However, the true Rory unites with her soon afterwards.

This is how Rory looks or rather how House makes Amy think Rory looks when he rages against her that she left him, ***again***:

[image]

Comment: I wonder what old Rory had been eating & drinking all those years ^_^

Comment: Yep that's it - I was watching the Dr. Who marathon on BBC America & saw the episode "The Girl Who Waited" - Amy separated from the Doctor and Rory and ages ~ 40 years - which got me to thinking about this.

Answer (score 9):

I believe this episode is ["The Doctor's Wife"](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Doctor%27s_Wife_(TV_story)).

Comment: I know that this is frowned upon but thanks for the response - would upvote all who answered but not enough points yet.

Comment: @JBR549 It's not frowned upon to comment "thank you" on a correct answer (or at least, it *shouldn't* be), so don't worry. Posting "thank you" as an answer is what's frowned upon.

Comment: @F1Krazy when you write a comment, the default text in the text field says to avoid comments like "+1" and "thanks". Though personally I agree, thanks comments should be fine.

Comment: @JBR549 - It's more than just a "thanks" - you also apologize for being unable to upvote the answer yet. No worries.

Answer (score -1):

Pretty sure it's [The Angels Take Manhattan](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Angels_Take_Manhattan) rather than the Doctors Wife. Rory gets zapped back in time by a Weeping Angel. The Doctor and Amy track him down in present day.

Comment: I recommend taking the [Tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour). Longer answers are preferred. Plus, you'll earn your first badge.